# How to check if key exists in swiftyJSON when json contain array with no keys

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

I know about swiftyJSON method exists() but it does not seem to work always as they say.
How can I get proper result in this case below? I cannot change JSON structure because I am getting this through client's API.

```
var json: JSON =  ["response": ["value1","value2"]]
if json["response"]["someKey"].exists(){
    print("response someKey exists")
}
```

Output:

```
response someKey exists
```

That shouldn't be printed because someKey does not exist. But sometimes that key comes from client's API, and i need to find out if it exists or not properly.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It doesn't work in your case because the content of `json["response"]` is not a dictionary, it's an array. SwiftyJSON can't check for a valid dictionary key in an array.

With a dictionary, it works, the condition is not executed, as expected:

```
var json: JSON =  ["response": ["key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"]]
if json["response"]["someKey"].exists() {
    print("response someKey exists")
}
```

The solution to your issue is to check if the content is indeed a dictionary before using `.exists()`:

```
if let _ = json["response"].dictionary {
    if json["response"]["someKey"].exists() {
        print("response someKey exists")
    }
}
```